# How to format date column in SQL Query in Joomla Model

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am trying to format a date column to YYYY in SQL query in Joomla so that i can use this in a where condition for selecting data. Because the column is always in '' the query produces error.

Please see an example below.

```
$query->where('(e.date_from LIKE '.$ref_year.' OR e.date_to LIKE '.$ref_year.')');

$query->where('(e.date_from->format('YYYY') LIKE '.$ref_year.' 
                OR e.date_to LIKE '.$ref_year.')');
```

Can you please help?
Thanks.

Comment: can you please show the expected value of `$ref_year`?

Comment: This is the definition of ref_year in the XML file.                                                      <field name="ref_year" type="text" class="inputbox"
size="4" label="COM_FIELD_REF_YEAR_LABEL"
description="COM_FIELD_REF_YEAR_DESC" required="true" />.        At run time ref_year could be any year. i.e 2008 or 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
$query->where("(DATE_FORMAT(e.date_from,'YYYY') = '".$ref_year."' 
                OR DATE_FORMAT(e.date_to,'YYYY') = '".$ref_year."')");
```

Comment: sorry. it does not work. its underlined in red.                                              Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'YYYY'

Comment: sorry i don't know how to do it. pls tell me.